# Do the close audits take into account edits?

Tags: discussion

I've just failed an audit even though (in my opinion at least) the question seems reasonable (not great mind you). I noticed that it's been edited in the last day and was originally closed over a week ago.

Am I just wrong in this case or are edits ignored when determining the results of audits?

Question is : [How can I form a parent child relation with these numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17304095/505722)